# Typo3 7.6.2 - Custom Styles RTE

Tags: typo3, rte, typo3-7.6.x

I got the newest Typo3 LTS version. Now i need to have some custom textstyles.

I can`t find anything useful on Google which works with version 7.6.2

The last configuration i tried is following:

```
RTE.default {
contentCSS = fileadmin/templates/css/typo3-RTE.css
}

RTE.default.proc.allowedClasses := addToList(tel, fax) 
RTE.default.buttons {
     textstyle.tags.span.allowedClasses := addToList(tel,fax) 
} 

RTE.default.proc.allowedClasses := removeFromList(csc-frame-frame1, csc-frame-frame2, important, name-of-person, detail) 

RTE.classes := removeFromList(csc-frame-frame1, csc-frame-frame2, important, name-of-person, detail) 

 RTE.classes.tel { 
     name = Telefonnummer 
         class = tel
 } 
RTE.classes.fax {
     name = Fax
         class = fax

}
```

I wanted to have the textstyles "Telefonnummer" and "Fax". As you can already guess, it does not work.

Beside of that none of the codes i found are working. Is there anyone having a solution for the newest LTS version of Typo3 and the RTE?

Answer (score 1):

My working example (Typo3 8.5.1):

**Page TsConfig**

```
            RTE.classes {
        custom-class {
            name = custom-class
            value = color:  #186900;
        }
    }

    ## Default RTE configuration
    RTE.default {
        proc.allowedClasses := addToList(custom-class)
        buttons.textstyle.tags.span.allowedClasses = custom-class
        buttons.textstyle.showTagFreeClasses = 1
        contentCSS = fileadmin/templates/css/rte.css
        ignoreMainStyleOverride = 1 
        useCSS = 1
    }

        ## Use same processing as on entry to database to clean content pasted into the editor
    RTE.default.enableWordClean.HTMLparser < RTE.default.proc.entryHTMLparser_db

        ## front end RTE configuration
    RTE.default.FE < RTE.default
    RTE.default.FE.FE >
    RTE.default.FE.userElements >
```

The rte.css file looks like this:

```
span.custom-class{
   color:  #186900;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please consider improving it by adding some explanation of how it solves the issue in the question!

Comment: in which Page TSConfig i must put this configuration code for have it to work on backennd?